# Set Model as Support - Support Settings?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, support-structures

I am currently trying to print an object, "model A", together with another object, "model B", that I want to use solely as a support structure. Regarding Ultimaker, I can set "model B" in **Per model settings** to **Print as support**; so far so good.

However, I can't figure out how to adjust the settings for the support; which pattern, if it has a support interface, etc. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured this out:

In Cura 5.1 (probably all 5.x) set "model B" to **Modify settings for overlaps**, instead of **Print as support**.

Choose **Cutting mesh** in the dropdown and select the relevant settings. I chose **Generate Support**, **Support Overhang Angle**, **Support Z Distance**, **Support Roof Thickness**, and **Support Floor Thickness**.

Enable **Generate Support** for "model B".

Slice and see if it fits your needs. I found that it didn't and it seems to inherit settings that can't be set per model from the general settings. As I didn't want to print support for the other model(s) I simply enabled support for the entire build, changed the settings I wanted changed for my "model B", and then disabled support for the entire build.